# Confused on how this line of Java code sorts in descending order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

first time posting here. I am trying to understand how this Java sort method actually sorts the array. I have already used a Java visualizer and it still makes zero sense to me. I understand that the sort method is taking in the array, and then uses two elements at a time to submit them to an expression (the second number minus the first number), but I do not understand how this value is used to sort the array:

```
Arrays.sort(arrayList,(Integer number1, Integer number2) -> number2 - number1)
```

(the arrayList elements can be whatever integers you would like)

Comment: the `Arrays.sort()` method doesn't even sort arraylists. It only sorts arrays

Comment: It's in the "convenience" of `Comparator` interface... `number1 -  number2` is the "default" (ascending) "int comparator" (see Integer source code...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If comparator function return positive value, numbers will be swapped.
=> if number2 > number1, then (number2 - number1) > 0 (positive) => swapped => number2 will be placed before and number1.

You can check the detail in function Comparator.compare:

```
        Arrays.sort(values, new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                if (o2 > o1) {
                    return 1; // need swap
                } else if (o2 < o1) {
                    return -1; // no swap
                }

                return 0; // no swap
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you understand how array.sort works. You will then need to understand how comparator works.

```html
obj1 > obj2 if x > 0.
obj1 < obj2 if x < 0.
obj1 equals obj2 if x = 0.
```

so in this case,

```
(Integer number1, Integer number2) -> number2 - number1
```

if num2 - num1 return a positive number meaning num2-num1 > 0, then it will be considered as num2 > num1 and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.sort(arrayList,(Integer number1, Integer number2) -> number2 - number1)
```

It has two parameters first one being an `array` and second one instance of `Comparator` class. `Arrays.sort()` method internally usages this `comparator` instance to compare elements while sorting. Here's one snippet from its internal implementation, here `c` is your instance of your Comparator.

```
  if (length < INSERTIONSORT_THRESHOLD) {
        for (int i=low; i<high; i++)
            for (int j=i; j>low && c.compare(dest[j-1], dest[j])>0; j--)
                swap(dest, j, j-1);
        return;
    }
```